# Loading node-spotify or spotify-web node modules in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, client

I'd like to use [Spotify's Playlist API](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-playlist.html) in-browser.  Unfortunately, their web api [only covers metadata](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/), the full API requires `libspotify` *et al*.  This seems to mean I either need to [set up a spotify API server](https://github.com/liesen/spotify-api-server) myself *or* use one of the node libraries wrapping the API, like [node-spotify-web](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-spotify-web) or [node-libspotify](https://github.com/Floby/node-libspotify) and use a tool like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html) or [gluejs](http://mixu.net/gluejs/) to expose that Node library to the browser.

Am I missing something here?  Really, I just want to be able to write browser-side, preferably API-driven JavaScript which will query a particular playlist.  Is the possibility of making an arbitrary node package available browser-side more fragile or contingent than I think?  *i.e.* Am I right in assuming I *can* embed one of these node packages browser-side?

I ask because I've tried to do this, encountering different issues for different libraries and tools, ranging from syntax errors in the generated gluejs output to missing requirement errors [like this one](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/issues/413) when using browserify.  I'll file separate questions for those, but the fact that I've run into issues with several different packages over several different tools made me think I was missing something--

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Libspotify has no use in browser, because nodejs modules using it require C++ parts, which are not available in browser.

Node-spotify-web works only in node, because browsers do most likely not allow cross-origin requests to the spotify servers.

So you'll have to:

1. Make your app an extension (extensions are allowed to do certain cross-origin requests)
2. Make use of a proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Author of node-spotify here, Michaiel Dral is correct. You can't use node-spotify in the browser, you would have to write your own service in node.js that makes use of it.

But Spotify just announced their new web API which now has playlist management, too: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/